# In OpenLayers 3, transformExtent to EPSG:8155 produces error

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, epsg

I'm trying to get the extent of a map using OpenLayers 3, so that I can use it in a CQL filter to limit the area of the WMS request to the area currently shown in the map extent. To do this, I have to transform the extent into the source layer's SRID coordinates, but I am getting an error when I try this. The code I'm using is:

```
var currentExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
transformedExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(currentExtent,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:8155');
```

I get the following error bubbling up in Firebug, which points to line 68 in http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/build/ol.js:

> TypeError: c is undefined function Je(b,c){var d=b.a,e=c.a,f;d in
>   Ke&&e in Ke[d]&&(f=Ke[d][e]);void 0===f&...

If I transform from 3857 to 4326 using the same syntax, otherwise, it works as expected, giving me coordinates that make sense for 4326:

```
transformedExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(currentExtent,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
```

8155 is the WYLAM SRID, and was added somewhat recently.  It looks like some of the formatting information is missing on [spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8155/).

Any ideas as to whether this is a problem that needs to be addressed in OpenLayers, Spatial Reference, or elsewhere?

Comment: The EPSG web service does not know code 8155 http://epsg-registry.org/ so it is probably not included in the newest official EPSG database version 8.8.1.